# Install Java JDK and JRE on Debian 8

Tags: debian, software-installation, java, jdk

I installed Debian 8, I would like to install Java JRE and JDK. I use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543603/installing-java-7-oracle-in-debian-via-apt-get) and it works.

But, I am afraid because it's a script hosted in a repository. I would like to understand why it doesn't work when I put the extract of [this JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) in `/usr/java/jre1.8.0_73` directory as [per the documentation](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml). I added the path variable with `PATH=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/bin:$PATH export PATH` as explained in [this doc](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) but it doesn't work.

Even if I try to install OpenJDK, the package isn't found. I don't understand why it's so complicated to install Java on Debian; it is very simple on Ubuntu. I would like someone give me step-by-step instructions to install it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’ll find OpenJDK 8 in Jessie backports (thanks to [Willian Paixao](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21240/willian-paixao) for reminding me):

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
apt update
```

will enable that, then

```
apt install -t jessie-backports openjdk-8-jdk
```

will install the JDK, or

```
apt install -t jessie-backports openjdk-8-jre
```

will install the JRE.

If you want Oracle’s JVM, see my answer to [Linux Mint Petra (16) Java Update from JRE 7 to JRE 8 breaks Graphics System?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/283909/86440), it’s quite simple too.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [official website](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage) you can build and install java as follows :

Add `contrib` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Download the `jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz` from [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Install the required package:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install 
apt-get install java-package
```

Build the `.deb` file then install it:

```
make-jpkg jdk-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz
dpkg -i oracle-java8-jdk_8u121_amd64.deb
```

Run the following command then select `jdk-8`:

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

sample output:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0         /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1         /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
* 2         /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-x64/jre/bin/java       318       manual mode
```

Run : `java -version`

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
```

Answer (score 1):

This method using PPA repositories are very unstable and frequently don't work out of Ubuntu's ecosystem. You better either install OpenJDK from Debian's official package repositories [[1]](https://packages.debian.org/). It's important to notice that by the time I write, *Open JDK 8* is not included in the stable repository. Means you need to add backports to `source.list` before installing it via `apt-get`. [[2]](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/openjdk-8-jdk)

I would rather download the Oracle tarball and simply extract it. Then as you mentioned, just append the `/bin` folder to `$PATH` and be happy.

Comment: Maybe even simpler than using the backports is just installing Debian 9.